# Filtering on linked table in Axapta/Dynamics Ax

Tags: axapta

I have a form in Axapta/Dynamics Ax (EmplTable) which has two data sources (EmplTable and HRMVirtualNetworkTable) where the second data source (HRMVirtualNetworkTable) is linked to the first on with "Delayed" link type.

Is there a way to set an filter on the records, based on the second data source, without having to change the link type to "InnerJoin"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use "Outer join" instead of "Delayed" then change the join mode programmaticly when there is search for fields on HRMVirtualNetworkTable.

Add this method to class SysQuery:

```
static void updateJoinMode(QueryBuildDataSource qds)
{
    Counter r;
    if (qds)
    {
        qds.joinMode(JoinMode::OuterJoin);
        for (r = 1; r <= qds.rangeCount(); r++)
        {
            if (qds.range(r).value() && qds.range(r).status() == RangeStatus::Open)
            {
                qds.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the executeQuery() on the EmplTable datasource:

```
public void executeQuery()
{;
    SysQuery::updateJoinMode(this.queryRun() ? this.queryRun().query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(HRMVirtualNetworkTable)) : this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(HRMVirtualNetworkTable)));    
    super();
}
```

Sometimes this.queryRun() return null so use this.query() instead.

**Update:**

Note that the above is not relevant for AX 2012 and later, where you can use query filters in outer joins. See [How to Use the QueryFilter Class with Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg881181.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmaticaly by joining QueryBuildDataSource or by extended filter (Alt+F3, Right click on datasorce, 1:n and find sev\condary DS)