# Circumvent Valid Time State in AOT queries

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have an AOT query in Dynamics AX 2012 which consists of the HcmWorker and HcmEmployment tables (among others). My problem is that when I create a report (not SSRS), or otherwise use this query, I only get the employees with a valid time state in HcmEmployment.

I would like to get all employees that has a record in this table, even if they doesn't have a current employment - and only once. The optimal solution is to get the record from HcmEmployment for the current employment, if it exists, and otherwise the last record with a start date before "now". However, I can accept a solution where it joins with the last start date.

I would prefer a solution where I do not need to add code every time I use it (i.e. solve it in the AOT query).

I have tried setting the validTimeStateDateTimeRange property on the query from code, which resulted in duplicate lines if the employee has several employments.

If I set the HcmEmployment datasource to ExistsJoin and firstOnly, then it works in a view, but not on reports (still duplicate records) :( Using this view on reports is not an option, because the users needs to be able to filter on DefaultDimension from HcmEmployment.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I "solved" my own problem...

For some reason the report did not correctly inherit the properties (`ExistsJoin`) from the AOT query. After dropping the query on the report again, some compilations and the following code in the query `init` method, it works :) No more duplicate records!

```
this.query().validTimeStateDateTimeRange(DateTimeUtil::minValue(), 
                                         DateTimeUtil::maxValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have conflicting options:

> I would like to get all employees that has a record in this table, even if they doesn't have a current employment

and:

> the users needs to be able to filter on DefaultDimension from HcmEmployment

If the user filters on the employment, should the employee then be printet, if the employment is not selected?

What you probably would like:

- If not filtering on `HcmEmployment` disable that data source (property `Enabled`).
- If filtering on `HcmEmployment` use an exists join.

In both cases find the maxof(ValidFrom), maxof(ValidTo) by an independent select.

Have a look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1097783/4509) to see how to edit query properties by code.

Or make two reports, one with and without a query to `HcmEmployment`.

Comment: If there isn't a record that matches the user filter, then the employee shouldn't be printed. If ANY record matches, then the employee should be printed ONCE. Your solution would require quite a bit of code at every place the query is used (MANY reports), which I'm hoping to avoid. But thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Then take the second option, use `ExistsJoin` then find the remaining fields in a seperat select.

Comment: If I use `ExistsJoin`, then I still get duplicate records. How do you suggest that I use `maxof`? The only way I can see that it can be used is to disable the HcmEmployment datasource and when iterating through the employees, I can check if they have an employment (by using the user ranges). Unfortunatly the performance would be terrible in databases with a lot of employees. It is a solution though and I will consider using it if I do not find a better one.

Comment: `ExistsJoin` will work if done correctly. For the rest, I cannot help as it depends on the exact requirements.